# Converting from iOS 9 Constraints to iOS 10

Tags: swift, constraints, ios9, ios10

I was following a video on youtube, running through how to build a messaging app in order to further my learning (still fairly new to Swift) The video is outdated as the constraints used are for iOS 9. The code is below:

```
 //iOS9 Constraints for views (text bubbles)
bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
bubbleWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true


//iOS9 Constraints for views (texts)
//textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
//textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

What I was wondering is, where can i go to further understand how these constraints where used? How can I figure out what constraints are needed for iOS 10?

Comment: WhichSwift Version are you using?  use bubbleView.rightAnchor. constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true as you seem to be using older swift version <3.0

Comment: Try to upgrade your Xcode